# Authentication failed on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've created an user on mongo db this is the comnand and the output

```
db.createUser({user:"appuser",pwd:"12345",roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "mydb" }]})
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "appuser",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "mydb"
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I try to enter with this command

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "appuser" --authenticationDatabase "mydb" -p
```

I get this error

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.4
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=mydb&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I created a root user and setted this option in `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

is something wrong?

Comment: in which database you run this command : `db.createUser({user:"appuser",pwd:"12345",roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "mydb" }]})` ?

Comment: I didn't select a database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official document of mongodb [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

> The database where you create the user (in this example, test) is that user's authentication database.

The database where we create the user will be used in the command to connect to MongoDB. We need to run `use [nameofdatabase]` to select the database before creating the user.

So, if you want to use `mydb` as the authentication database, you need to run these commands :

```
use mydb;
db.createUser({user:"appuser",pwd:"12345",roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "mydb" }]});
```

Then you can connect to your MongoDB with : `mongo --port 27017 -u "appuser" --authenticationDatabase "mydb" -p`